# How to get the ARN of an EC2 instance in AWS-CDK

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cdk

I am creating a EC2 instance using CfnInstance in CDK and I would like to use the ARN later in an IAM role, so I can give permission to that specific resource and to avoid to use *. How can I access the ARN of the EC2 instance just created. The code is as follows:

```
    instance_profile = self.create_instance_profile()
    self.instance = ec2.CfnInstance(self, 'Client',
        image_id = image_id,
        instance_type = instance_type,
        subnet_id = subnet_id,
        iam_instance_profile = instance_profile.ref,
        security_group_ids = [cluster_security_group_id],
        user_data = core.Fn.base64('\n'.join(self.user_data_commands)),
        tags = [{ 'key': 'Name', 'value': 'MskEc2Client' }],
    )


 def create_instance_profile(self):
    role = iam.Role(self, 'Role', assumed_by = iam.ServicePrincipal('ec2.amazonaws.com'))
    ssm_policy_statement = iam.PolicyStatement(
        resources = ['*'],  #TODO GIVE PERMISSION TO THE SPECIFIC RESOURCE (EC2)
        actions = [
            'ssm:UpdateInstanceInformation', 'ssmmessages:CreateControlChannel', 
            'ssmmessages:CreateDataChannel', 'ssmmessages:OpenControlChannel', 'ssmmessages:OpenDataChannel'])

    ssm_policy = iam.Policy(self, 'SessionManagerPolicy', statements = [ssm_policy_statement])
    self.add_w12_suppression(ssm_policy, 'Session Manager actions do not support resource level permissions')
    ssm_policy.attach_to_role(role)

    msk_policy = iam.Policy(self, 'MskPolicy', #TODO GIVE PERMISSION TO SPECIFIC RESOURCES (EC2)
        statements = [iam.PolicyStatement(resources = ['*'], actions = ['kafka:DescribeCluster', 'kafka:GetBootstrapBrokers'])]
    )

    self.add_w12_suppression(msk_policy, 'MSK actions do not support resource level permissions')
    msk_policy.attach_to_role(role)

    cfn_role = role.node.default_child
    return iam.CfnInstanceProfile(self, 'InstanceProfile', roles = [cfn_role.ref])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the default [return value](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html#aws-properties-ec2-instance-return-values) of the instance to construct the arn to populate the resources

```py
ssm_policy_statement = iam.PolicyStatement(
    resources = [f'arn:{self.partition}:ec2:{self.region}:{self.account}:instance/{self.instance.ref}'],
    actions = [
        'ssm:UpdateInstanceInformation', 'ssmmessages:CreateControlChannel', 
        'ssmmessages:CreateDataChannel', 'ssmmessages:OpenControlChannel', 'ssmmessages:OpenDataChannel'
    ]
)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way of obtaining the ARN for the EC2 instance. You can use the `CfnInstance` type and `cdk.Fn.getAtt()` to obtain the ARN for your ec2 instance as below.

```
import * as cdk from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import { CfnInstance } from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-ec2';
import * as ec2 from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-ec2';

_computeInstance: ec2.Instance;

const cfnInstance = this._computeInstance.node.defaultChild as CfnInstance;
const instanceArn = cdk.Fn.getAtt(cfnInstance.logicalId, "Arn").toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to construct the ARN yourself, you should use [format_arn](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk/Stack.html#aws_cdk.Stack.format_arn). This will work with any partition (aws, aws-cn, aws-us-gov), and automatically figure out the region and account id.

```
instance_arn = core.Stack.of(self).format_arn(
  service="ec2",
  resource="instance",
  resource_name=self.instance.ref,
  arn_format=core.ArnFormat.SLASH_RESOURCE_NAME,
)
```

Comment: Any idea how to obtain the ARN of the root volume of the EC2 instance using CDK? I need it for AWS Backup service to backup Volume

Comment: If you create it yourself and pass it to the instance, you should have access to it. Otherwise a custom resource can find it.